# Aero not working after Windows 7 update

Tags: windows-7, aero

After the latest Windows 7 update, the Windows Aero theme has stopped working.

I have tried restarting services, switching themes, etc.
Redone the indexing and is at 7.1 score. The Windows Aero troubleshooter cant find any problems.

I think that this is most of the stuff I have tried.

Comment: Please tell us your graphics card model and other hardware specs.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't include any details, so take a look [at this question](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproui/thread/1fff4208-c257-42f7-b9f4-423b6e8e2a5f). Maybe it will help you.
There are several answers, maybe this is your answer:

> I had enabled some features from the Ease of Access Center.
>    I made a choice in the  section "Make the computer easier to see".
>    Under "Make things on the screen easier to see", I had checked,
>   "Remove background   images (where available). As soon as I unchecked
>   that I, again,   was able to see my Desktop Background.

Comment: It is now solved. it was an old Display Link Core driver that was lingering in the background. uninstalled it and now it works fine.